# r column values in sql where statement

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have a dataset and I am trying to pass the contents of a specific column into the SQL where statement.

For example, assuming iris is my dataset

```
       data(iris)
       head(iris)

       Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
       5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
       4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
       4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
       4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
       5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
       5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

I want to pass the contents of column Species { setosa, setosa, setosa.....setosa} to my sql query where statement

```
sqlQuery(abcd, paste("Select * from TestTableName1 
                       where WHERE DESCRIPTION 
                          IN (values of Species column from r dataframe)");
```

Need help here

Comment: `sqlQuery` doesn't come from the `sqldf` package. It comes from the `RODBC` package. Also, you have two `where` in your select statement.

Comment: And you can try this for your query: `strwrap(paste("Select * from TestTableName1 where WHERE DESCRIPTION IN (" , paste( unique(iris$Species),  collapse=' ,') , ")"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is really about string manipulation (it's incidental that your string will eventually be passed to `sqldf`), and the answer is that you paste it together, or use `sprintf` if you're feeling fancy:

```
vals = paste(paste0('"', levels(iris$Species), '"'), collapse = ", ")
vals
## [1] "\"setosa\", \"versicolor\", \"virginica\""

vals.paren = paste0("(", vals, ")")

qry = paste("select * from table where description in ", vals.paren)
qry
## [1] "select * from table where description in  (setosa, versicolor, virginica)"

# sprintf makes the bounding parentheses cleaner

qry = sprintf("select * from table where description in (%s)", vals)
qry
## [1] "select * from table where description in (setosa, versicolor, virginica)"
```

Comment: Are you adding `>` in the beginning of the lines on purpose? I have a great urge to edit this answer...

Comment: Just copy/pasting from my console, being lazy. Edits welcome. (Though I suppose I could take the time myself.) *Edit:* beat me to it, thanks!

Comment: this is returning a list without "" around values. It won't work in the SQL Where clause.

Comment: @Giacomo edited to add quotes.

Answer (score 1):

By prefacing any function call with `fn$` from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) string interpolation is enabled on its arguments.  See `?fn` for more info.  This is often used with `sqldf` in the [sqldf package](http://sqldf.googlecode.com) but can be used with any function as we show here. In particular inserting `$variable` into a string argument of the function call substitutes the value of that variable into that string:

```
library(gsubfn)
lvls <- toString(shQuote(levels(iris$Species)))

fn$sqlQuery(abcd,  "select * from TestTableName1 where DESCRIPTION in ($lvls)")
```

or if we want to examine the string first:

```
sql <- fn$identity("select * from TestTableName1 where DESCRIPTION in ($lvls)")
cat(sql, "\n") # look at sql string

sqlQuery(abcd, sql)
```

The output from the `cat` statement is:

```
select * from TestTableName1 where DESCRIPTION in ("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
```