# Query in SQL with conditions in an R dataframe

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I'm relatively new to R and SQL and I'm stuck with a query, hoping someone can answer my question.

I'm using the RODBC package and I need to do a rather sophisticated query.

I have an R dataframe that looks like this :

```
donor_id <- c(1,2)
date <- c(as.Date('2011-01-01'), as.Date('2013-06-14'))
df <- cbind(donor_id, date)
```

And a big database that has donation dates for every of my donor_id.

I want to add a column to my data frame from the database. This column will be the number of donations that each of my donor_id has made before the date in my data frame.

So according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990387/rodbc-using-data-frame-in-a-join-on-sqlquery), there are 3 solutions :

- Query the whole database and work from there (takes forever)
- Save the data frame into the server and join them in a query (I don't have sufficient rights for this)
- Pass the conditions from the data frame, which is what I'm trying to do

I have drawn ideas from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595082/r-column-values-in-sql-where-statement) for the general MO and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517681/sql-sum-with-condition) for the sum of rows.

The general idea is to merge my data frame and the query

```
merge(df,query, by='donor_id')
```

The query looks like this :

```
paste("select donor_id, SUM(CASE WHEN donation_date <= ",df$date," 
THEN collection_count ELSE 0 END) AS 'ncol' from fact_collection 
GROUP BY donor_id"))
```

However, when I'm trying this, I get the following error message :

> Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Which means that my merge cannot recognize the donor_id for some reason.

Comment: can you do `names(df)` and `names(query)`? Do they both have only single `"donor_id"` column? Also need to check the whether any additional punctuation,spaces or capital letters for the column name.

Comment: df does have only one donor_id column, however query has no column. Executing query produces an error because the argument df$date is not recognized as a valid condition

Comment: @addicted But `query` cannot be executed on its own because it needs to select the correct row with `df$date`. The correct row is selected with the `merge` command

Comment: you know you cannot merge a dataframe `(df)` with query string `query`, right? `merge` works for joining 2 dataframe, not a dataframe and a query. Your `query <- paste("...", df$Date, "...")` will result in a vector of 2 strings, not dataframe.

Comment: Yes, I know. my code is actually `merge(df,sqlQuery(connection,query), by=donor_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `df` has more than one row, you cannot use `sqlQuery` by itself to execute a series of queries contained in an R character vector. As `?sqlQuery` states, argument `query` must be a valid SQL statement. The output of your `paste` statement would look something like this:

```
[1] "select donor_id, SUM(CASE WHEN donation_date <= 2016-01-01
THEN collection_count ELSE 0 END) AS 'ncol' from fact_collection 
GROUP BY donor_id"
[2] "select donor_id, SUM(CASE WHEN donation_date <= 2016-01-02
THEN collection_count ELSE 0 END) AS 'ncol' from fact_collection 
GROUP BY donor_id"
[3] "select donor_id, SUM(CASE WHEN donation_date <= 2016-01-03
THEN collection_count ELSE 0 END) AS 'ncol' from fact_collection 
GROUP BY donor_id"
```

etc.

Instead of trying to run a vector of queries in a single sqlQuery statement, consider using a function from the `apply` family, then using `rbind` to aggregate the data frames into one, e.g.:

```
all_results <- apply(df$date,1,function(value){
query <- paste("select donor_id, SUM(CASE WHEN donation_date <= ",value," 
THEN collection_count ELSE 0 END) AS 'ncol' from fact_collection 
GROUP BY donor_id"))
result <- sqlQuery(connection,query)
return(result)
}) # returns a list of results in separate data frames

results_df <- do.call(rbind, all_results) # combine list of dataframes into a monolith
```